# Order of operations when dealing with paths in a topological space.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space with $\alpha,\beta:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ two paths such that $\alpha(0)=x_0,~\alpha(1)=\beta(0)=x_1 $ and $\beta(1)=x_2$. Suppose I would like to evaluate the expression $\alpha^{-1}*\beta^{-1}$. Should I first compute the inverses and then multiply the paths or multiply the paths and take their inverses ? Here are the results of performing the calculation in both routes.

Invert then multiply:
\begin{align}\alpha^{-1}*\beta^{-1} &=\alpha(1-s)*\beta(1-s) \\ &=\begin{cases}\alpha(2-2s)&&0\leq s\leq 1/2\\\beta(1-2s)&&1/2 \leq s \leq 1\end{cases}\end{align}

Multiply then invert:
$$\begin{align}\alpha^{-1}*\beta^{-1}&= \begin{cases}\alpha^{-1}(2s)&&0 \leq s \leq 1 \\ \beta^{-1}(2s-1) && 1/2 \leq s \leq 1\end{cases} \\&= \begin{cases}\beta(1-2s)&&0 \leq s \leq 1/2 \\  \alpha(2-2s)&& 1/2 \leq s \leq 1\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Just incase, my definitions (Nakahara, 2003) of inverting and multiplying are
$$\alpha*\beta=\begin{cases}\alpha(2s)&&0\leq s \leq 1/2\\\beta(2s-1)&& 1/2 \leq s \leq 1\end{cases}$$
and $\alpha^{-1}(s)=\alpha(1-s)$. I would think that first you multiply and then you invert, since this would give $(\alpha*\beta)^{-1}=\alpha^{-1}*\beta^{-1}$ which makes sense.

Comment: I have just realised the first route doesn't make sense (it is not defined for s=0). Have I done something wrong in the computation or is it not supposed to make sense?

Comment: You did the computation wrong, it should be $\alpha(1-2s)$, since you substitute $2s$ in for $s$ in $\alpha(1-s)$.

Comment: Right, of course, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You invert and then multiply.

The other way around is written $(\alpha * \beta)^{-1}$ and you can check that $(\alpha * \beta)^{-1} = \beta^{-1} * \alpha^{-1}$

Comment: OK. So if I want to compute $(\alpha*\beta)^{-1}$ would this be right?
\begin{align}(\alpha*\beta)^{-1}&=\bigg ( \begin{cases} \alpha(2s)&&0\leq s \leq 1/2 \\ \beta(2s-1) && 1/2 \leq s \leq 1 \end{cases}\bigg)^{-1} \\ &=\begin{cases} \alpha(2-2s)&&0\leq 1-s  \leq1/2 \\ \beta(1-2s) && 1/2 \leq 1-s \leq 1 \end{cases}  \\ &= \begin{cases} \beta(1-2s) && 0 \leq s \leq 1/2 \\ \alpha(2-2s) && 1/2 \leq s \leq 1 \end{cases}.
 \end{align}